# How can i connect to oracle database as sysdba using bltoolkit?

Tags: oracle, bltoolkit

i can connect to oracle normal user successfully but when i try to connect sys user i got this error.

```
ORA-28009: connection as SYS should be as SYSDBA or SYSOPER
```

because i have to connect as sysdba but how can do it on bltoolkit ?

How can solve this problem ?

I have to connect as sys user to oracle using bltoolkit

My Connstring:

Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_‌​DATA=(SID=prod)));User Id=sys;Password=manager;DBA Privilege=SYSDBA;Data Source=oracle;

Comment: Show us the connect string. But why you need to connect as sysdba using BL Toolkit?

Answer (score 1):

Oracle allows database administrators to connect to an Oracle Database with either SYSDBA or SYSOPER privileges. This is done through the DBA Privilege attribute of the ConnectionString.

```
//Connect SYS/SYS as SYSDBA   
con.ConnectionString = "User Id=SYS;Password=SYS;" + 
  "DBA Privilege=SYSDBA;Data Source=oracle;";
```

Comment: I use bltoolkit3 for this project and i got error:Keyword not supported: 'dba privilege'... my connection string:Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=prod)));User Id=sys;Password=manager;DBA Privilege=SYSDBA;Data Source=oracle;

Comment: The Oracle ManagedDataAccess driver will allow dba priviledge to function.  Perhaps the driver you are using doesn't support that. I think I used the default .NET oracle driver and it didn't support DBA Privilege.